# Is it correct to say "actual self"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

Is it correct to use "actual self" in the following context:

> As she was dead long time ago, her descendants could not have possibly
>   seen her actual self.

Comment: Yes, it is appropriate.

Comment: As she *has been dead* for a long time or As she *died* a long time ago. I would suggest using "*met her in person*".

Comment: There are other, probably better, ways to word it, but the last part is fine as stated.   As Rathony points out, though, the first part could use some work.

Comment: Dunno whether it is pertinent here, but be aware that "*actual*" and "*actually*" are **false friends** for certain languages, such as French. In such languages, the apparent friend actually (!) means "*current*" or "*currently*" in English. In English, "*actual*" and "*actually*" are essentially synonymous with "*real*" and "*really*", respectively. This is a problem for native English speakers who encounter such misuses of "*actual*" and "*actually*", especially when those words do make sense in the current context (but they do not mean what was intended).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing especially wrong with the term *actual self*, though to some extent, I am having to guess at what is means.

If you mean her *real self*, as opposed to her *pretended or false self*, then why not use ***real self*** ?

I think we need some wider context from you to understand exactly what you are getting at with *actual self*.

Incidentally the opening clause of your sentence I think needs to read *As she had been dead a long time...* or *As she died a long time ago...*, in order to be grammatical.